# Multiple Hive external tables on single file.

Tags: hadoop, hive

As per my understanding, creating multiple external tables in Hive on the same file and                    then inserting records to any 1 table affects all other tables which are created on the same file. Is there a way to avoid this ? In other words, is there a way to affect only the inserted table and not all the tables that are created on the hdfs file ??

Answer (score 0):

No, a table (or partition) has exactly one directory location on HDFS (or other filesystem), and all files in that location will be considered part of the table.

When you insert into one table, it creates a new file in that directory. There is no way I know of to exclude only certain files within the same directory from a table.